# Effect of Sample Size on Model Mean Squared Error

Tags: regression, simulation, linear

I am studying Linear Regression by performing a simulation study with different sample sizes.
As I increase the sample size the mean squared error seems to reduce but with a very large sample size (5000) the mean squared error seems to increase again.

It would be really helpful if you could explain this pattern.

Comment: Do you see large fluctuation in MSE due to sample size? They should be only due to randomness in the sample and should not be large. MSE should converge to its population counterpart as the sample size grows. I assume you have representative samples since you are doing simulations; non-representative samples could be another explanation of the fluctuations that you are seeing.

Comment: The fluctuation is not very large. I was wondering if this is happening due to introduction of a systematic bias.

Comment: How many iterations are you using per sample size? Are you using the same data generating process each time?

Comment: Right now I am running only one iteration per sample size. I am using rnorm() function in R to generate the explanatory variables and the noise parameter

Answer (score 2):

MSE = SSE/(n-2) , now squared error = Variance * sample size. So if you will keep the error variance constant and increase the sample size .. the SSE will also increase. Hence, both the numerator and denominator for MSE will increase, and you cannot conclude if MSE will monotonically increase/decrease by changing the sample size. But essentially what you will observe is, if you increase the sample size, the MSE will converge to the error variance as MSE is an unbiased estimator for the variance.